# Qt incorrectly lays widgets on top of each other

Tags: c++, qt

In Qt 4.8.5 32-bit and VS2010, I'm trying to create a Window as shown in this screenshot from QtDesigner:

[image]

When I run the application, the widgets get laid down on top of each other :
[image]

In the Console, I see this :
[image]

Does anybody have any idea why this is happening?
Here is my code :

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(){
      ui = new Ui::AView();
      ui->setupUi(this);
    }
    ~MainWindow();
...

 private:
    Ui::AView* ui;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the screenshot of QtDesigner, I see that your UI is for a `QWidget`, but you are applying it to a `QMainWindow`. This causes the problem, as the handling of main window is different to other widgets.

I don't know of a way to change the base class for a UI file. Maybe the best way is to create a new file, select the mainwindow template, and copy/paste the content from the old file.

Another option would be to have a `QWidget`, set it up with the UI, and add it as the main window's central widget:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(){
      ui = new Ui::AView();
      QWidget *wgt = new QWidget;
      ui->setupUi(wgt);
      this->setCentralWidget(wgt);
    }
    ~MainWindow();
...

 private:
    Ui::AView* ui;
}
```

Comment: that did it! Thank you king_nak, I oversaw this. 
What I did was just create a new ui using the MainWindow template, select everything from the previous, copy and pasted it inside, regenerated the ui.h and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow, public Ui::AView
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(){
      setupUi(this);
    }
    ~MainWindow();
}
```